# Importing Gradle project leaves entire project behind

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx

I have a libgdx project that has multiple modules like 'core' and 'desktop' within the project root. I was missing the Gradle tab. I wanted to add new dependencies to the project and needed to sync the project.

Apparently reimporting is the way to fix that.

Issues:

- Importing the project just gives me an empty project with a .gradle and .idea folder without any of my project.
- Copying the projects manually just adds the modules as normal directories, the Gradle build fails.
- Adding the modules through project structure adds them as separate project roots, the build fails again.

Errors:

```
Cause: invalid type code: 53
```

https://pastebin.com/d8VRbJp9

https://pastebin.com/hSzeW0ai

Build:

https://pastebin.com/BwkCJMaD

Comment: Can you link your build.gradle please>

Comment: Does the project build from the command line Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your build.gradle doesn't have any source setting going on.

The easiest way to remedy this is to create a new project using the setup tool (I personally prefer [this one](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-setup) and then just copy your source files and assets across. After that, only change the build file to name the project etc. try not to fiddle with other things.

I am unsure as to whether this next method will work but you can try it. If you really want to keep your original project, try adding the following to the build.gradle under each specific project:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs 'src'
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir 'assets'
```

So each project should look like:

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs 'src'
    sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir 'assets'
    ...
}
```

If anyone tries this and it doesn't work, let me know and I'll remove it from the answer.